# VBA to loop through each row

Tags: vba, excel, solver

I have to iterate through 163 rows. Solver changes these variables cells AU4 to DH4 and this goes down to 163rd row. The objective cell FN$2 is the same and it needs to be maximized so it would be adding all the cells. The constraints change for every row as well so foor the first row it will be AU1 and AZ should be 1

Is there a way to do that

```
Sub FindMaxYs()
  Dim i As Integer
 ActiveSheet.Cells(4, AU).Select
 For i = 4 To 163
ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Select
SolverReset
SolverOk SetCell:=ActiveCell, MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, 
ByChange:=Range(ActiveCell.Offset(4, AU), ActiveCell.Offset(0, DH)), _
    Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
 Next i
 End Sub
End Sub
```

can someone give a guidance?

Comment: When you use `ActiveCell.Offset(4, AU)` or `ActiveCell.Offset(0, DH)`, what are you hoping to achieve? I see no AU or DH var, declared or assigned. Do you mean column AU or DH like `Cells(i + 4, "AU")` ?

Comment: Suggest you put `Option Explicit` at the top of the code page and work through your var declaration and assignment issues first.

Answer (score 0):

> Solver changes these variables cells AU4 to DH4 and this goes down to 163rd row.

The column identifiers AU and AH need to be quoted strings when used as the column argument in Cells. Further, the .Offset command takes arguments that the number of rows and columns away from the original. If you use column AU as the column offset argument, you are stating that you want something 44 columns away from where the offset started.

```
Sub FindMaxYs()
    Dim i As long

    with ActiveSheet

        For i = 4 To 163
            SolverReset
            SolverOk SetCell:=union(.Cells(i, "AU"), .Cells(i, "DH")), _
                     MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, _
                     ByChange:=.Range(.Cells(i, "AU"), .Cells(i, "DH")), _
                     Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
         Next i

    end with

End Sub
```

The above goes through a loop of 4 to 163.

Comment: This makes sense. Do you know how i can incporate a constraint such that for an i row  it should AUi=0 and BFi=0

Comment: Also, the row changing should be AU5:DH5  AU6:DH6

Comment: I really don't have enough information to run a full test bench example but you try the above edits and maybe work from there. The AU5:DH5 AU6:DH6 correction should have been pretty obvious.